# OAuth Bearer Token Not Working for WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I have gone through a lot of docs but it seems my problem is strange.
I have configured Oauth but I am not able to get the bearer token back. whenever I hit api to get the token, I get 200 but nothing back in response(I am expecting bearer token). Below is the config:

```
 public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions oAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider()
        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
        });

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        //config.Filters.Add(new );
        //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        // There can be multiple exception loggers. (By default, no exception loggers are registered.)
        //config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        //enable cors origin requests
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);            
    }
}


 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="config"></param>
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationAttribute("bearer")); //added this
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    }

public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var form = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
        if (myvalidationexpression)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "AuthorizedUser"));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Provided username and password is incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I launch the APi and hit /token, I get this as below:

[API Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTtpc.png)

Answer (score 3):

I think that code you have written in WebApiConfig.cs to suppress host authentication and some other code is creating the issue.
I have a working example for bearer token generation in web API, which is working properly and generating token.

WebApiConfig.cs file code:

```
      public static class WebApiConfig
        {
            public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
                // Web API configuration and services

                // Web API routes
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
            }
        }
```

Startup.cs Code:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebAPI.Startup))]
namespace WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);


        }
        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
             OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
             {
                 AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                 TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                 AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
                 Provider=new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
                 //AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
             };
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions {
                Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
            }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Controller to check authorization call after adding bearer token in the request.

```
 public class TokenTestController : ApiController
    {
        [Authorize]
        public IHttpActionResult Authorize()
        {
            return Ok("Authorized");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I removed all the unnecessary code but still issue persists. Also, the issue is, I am not getting the token back when I am hitting /token endpoint.

Comment: Are you using asp.net MVC web API or Asp.net core API?

Comment: I am using Asp.Net MVC web Api. However, I created the project from scratch once again and everything works fine now. Not sure what had gone wrong in the older one.

Comment: Ok, if my answer helps you can upvote or mark as answer.

Comment: Just done that. I have posted a concern at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/332   Any idea on that?

Answer (score -2):

install the following package

Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

Comment: There is nothing in the question that suggests that this is caused by a missing package (Much less one that's included by default!). This is a runtime issue, if this package were missing and the project makes use of it then the application wouldn't even be in a runnable state.

Comment: Dear the common flow is what you are telling, but its use its internal packages and when that package is missing its not generating token, if you want to check then create the project and test yourself, i have wasted 3 days and then comeup with solution.

Try first then make a negative voting.

Comment: In that case, you should [edit] your answer and include these details to provide more context. This would make your answer much more useful to those who might come across the same issue later on.